# Android Studio error "Android resource compilation failed"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I recently downloaded Android studio for windows 10 and this was my first project the ide works fine but when i test it it gives this error shown in picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAXlL.png)

Here is the java code.

```
package pro.haha_yes_appss.goproooooooooooooooooooooooo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class youtube extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())
        webView.loadurl("https://www.youtube.com/c/TuckerBudzyn/featured")
    }
}
```

And if it has to do anything with my xml style file then here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="https://www.youtube.com/c/TuckerBudzyn/featured">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>

<WebView
android:id="@/id+webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ps i was following a tutorial here is its link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUXui5ItBkM

Comment: also my app uses internet if that makes any difference

Comment: can you please show your manifest ?

Comment: the id of the webView should be :
android:id="@+id/webview"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id of the webview in your layout file should be in this format:

`android:id="@+id/webview"`

not

`android:id="@/id+webview"`